# execution flow button in a SPO library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have created an SP document library with an execution flow button that extracts the zip files when the users click it. The extract file locations are the same as the zip file in the document library.

My issue is that the extract files have the button option as well. Can I make that button available only for the zip files?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show/hide the JSON formatting button based on the file name using `display` property like:

```
"display": "=if(endsWith([$FileLeafRef], '.zip'), 'block', 'none')",
```

**Full example**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"edf627d9-20f4-45ba-8bc9-4494bf2ff1be\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "display": "=if(endsWith([$FileLeafRef], '.zip'), 'block', 'none')",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "txtContent": "Extract file here"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]